# Thread pool and fork in c

Tags: multithreading, fork, pool, pstree

I have a program that executes find command with pipes and fork. 
When I use one main pthread and one pthread per find i have these results (for 2 find) in pstree:

```
sysexplorer─┬─2*[find]
            └─{sysexplorer}
```

when I use one main pthread and a thread pool(with 10 threads) for the find i have these results (for 2 find again) in pstree:

```
sysexplorer─┬─2*[find]
            └─11*[{sysexplorer}]
```

is that correct? I believe it must be something like that:

```
sysexplorer─┬─10*[find]
            └─1*[{sysexplorer}] or sysexplorer─┬─11*[{sysexplorer}]
```

but I have no experience so I cannot be sure.

fork is called exactly before find. is that a reason?

If this is wrong what do I have to do?

Comment: how do you execute the find command ? where do you execute it ? (in main or in thread function) ?

Comment: find command executed from a function that is given to thread(or thread pool) as the argument function to execute.